# Geth console output: "broke chain ordering" and "potential rewrite attack"

Tags: go-ethereum, console

I sometimes run geth with this command: 'geth -rpc' It usually prints a bunch of uninteresting status info, but this morning it started printing this:

```
I0916 07:49:32.384544 eth/handler.go:295] Peer c797a594f5d7db60 [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0916 07:49:39.880931 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1087] Peer 562796b19d43d79d [hs 0.00/s,
    bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: head header set
    (item 0) broke chain ordering: requested 1919809, got 2269765
I0916 07:49:50.690184 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 7603e0ec309a49e3 [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0916 07:51:23.101820 eth/downloader/downloader.go:1195] Peer 627bdf5515ce98ce [hs 0.00/s,
    bs 0.00/s, rs 0.00/s, ss 0.00/s, miss    0, rtt 20s]: potential rewrite attack:
    #1963453 [00000000…] <= #1963453 limit
I0916 07:51:34.064429 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 00af8248d908e266 [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping
I0916 07:51:44.748102 eth/handler.go:295] Peer 494b9fe56dfad18d [eth/63]: timed out DAO fork-check, dropping
```

I'm not worried about the "DAO fork" message (they happen all the time), but what does "broke chain ordering" and "potential rewrite attack" mean?

Sounds bad.